# How can i close the session after x time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In ASP.NET on IIS 7.5, how can I close the session after an amount of time (lets say 5 hours), even if the user is still working and there is no idle time?

Is there a property in IIS or should I do it in code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried such a solution before but here's what come into mind :

In your `global.asax` handle `SessionStart` and when a new session is started create a new (Asynchronous )Task that starts a timer (a timer that execute once after 5 hours and calls Session.Abandon() :

Something like this :

```
new Task(()=>{
var timer=new Timer{Interval=DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), Elpased+=(obj,args)=>{
session.Abandon();
((Timer)obj).Stop();
((Timer)obj).Dispose();

}
}).Start()
```

As I told you I haven't test it and since everything is working asynchronously here it might led to unknown situations.

(BTW as far as I know timer will already run in another thread so no Task is needed :) )

**Update**

OK, It seems that we can't hold a reference to a HtmlStateSession. Thus here's another approach that I think it can help: In this approach we hold a registery of session id and start time of each session in a static dictionary and when a request begins we check if its session (according to its session id) has been out there more than 5 hours and if that is the case we Abonden the session.(and remove the id from dictionary of course)

There's no need to have thousands of timers this way and we don't expire the sessions right away but we wait until the next time that user sends us a request.

Comment: In asp.net, non-request-handling threads do not have access to `Session`.

Comment: So,  if i have 1000 users online , i'll have 1000 timers on 1000 threads ?

Comment: That's the beauty of clousers. When you use a lambda expression to build a function it save a reference to all local resources that are used in it.I believe you can access to the newly built session via SessionStart event args.

Comment: Hm, again: saved reference to `Session` is stale once the the processing of the request is finished.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know how it would scale with 1000 timers

Comment: Hm Haven't known about that . If that's the case then I am afraid there's no straight forward way to make a session expired.Then I should update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the web.config?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm also assuming you have a basic site with no load balancing or session state servers.  Those require different approaches.

Comment: this config is for timeout for idle (not working )' i asked about closing session for working user

Comment: Missed that, so log the time the user logged into the system, and then have something count 5 hours and then close the session.  Quartz.net for server & javascript for client side depending your approach.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up windows task scheduler to run an aspx page that will check how long the user is logged in and according to it, to decide if to close the session or not.

(You can save in your database, a log-in time for each user).